# Custom keyboard layout not showing in Settings

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am trying to create a new keyboard layout where two keys are inverted with each other.

This is what I have done:

Edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/se` to add:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "kinesis" {

    // Modifies the basic Swedish layout to place aring correctly

    include "latin(type2)"
    include "se(basic)"

    name[Group1]="Swedish (kinesis)";

    key <BKSL>  { [     aring,      Aring       ]   };
    key <AD11>  { [apostrophe,   asterisk,        acute,     multiply ] };

};
```

Edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst` to add to the section `! variant`:

```
kinesis         se: Swedish (kinesis)
```

Restarted X.

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3a%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) mentions something about `rules/evdev.html`, which I do not have (Ubuntu 14.04). It mentions also "adding the file", but I did not create any new file, only completed the existing `symbols/se`. I also tried to clear `/var/lib/xkb` from `*.xkm`, no difference.

How do I make this new variant of the layout to show up in my Settings->Text Entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to add the entry also to the file `evedev.xml`, something on the line of:

```
    <variant>
      <configItem>
        <name>kinesis</name>
        <description>My special kinesis</description>
      </configItem>
    </variant>
```

Near where the other variants for the `se` layouts are defined.

...and/or modify the correspondent `base.xml`, `base.lst` files.

I really do not know exactly how it works, thanks to the quite sparse documentation, but [I managed to have my Spanish variant](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/) working (tested in Xubuntu but should work in all DE... modulo bugs).

And yes, removing `*.xkm` files is needed too. And yes, the `.xml` file should be generated by the `.lst` file, but I am unable to find how.

Comment: This was working, thank you. It would be nice to know why it's not done automatically.

Comment: @Gauthier --- if you find it, please edit the answer or comment and I will.

Comment: I wonder if the help page has a typo, and if it should say xml instead of html (I was waiting to accept in order to see if anyone would explain why the changes had to be done in two places).

Comment: @Gauthier --- yes, probably a typo.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your custom settings to /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst and /usr/share/X11/xkb/evdev.xml under the section keycodes.

here's a [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3a%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) to the ubuntu-help-page.

Comment: Editing the xml was needed, but there's no mention of this in the help page (which I also linked to)